# How to get child - Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how to get name child

[image]

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('order/');
const dbref = ref.child('items');

ref.on('child_added', data =>  {
    console.log(data.key, data.val().name);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('order/');
const dbref = ref.child('items');
```

Sets up a reference to `/order/items`. There is no such location in the data you show.

What you want instead:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('order/');

ref.on('child_added', snapshot =>  {
    // snapshot now contains the data of -KmDWQ...
    snapshot.child("items").forEach((itemSnapshot) => {
        console.log(itemSnapshot.key, itemSnapshot.val().name);
    });
});
```